# Unlocking a Windows computer through the CMD prompt

Tags: windows, cmd

Let's say I had an "NT AUTHORITY\SYSTEM" command shell on my locked Windows computer (at the login prompt) and I would like to get log in as user X (as if I logged in normally with their username and password). User X is a Domain user and the computer can't connect to a domain controller. How would I achieve this?